# Strip and fetch text content from each nested div on a page

Tags: php, html-content-extraction

I have got an HTML from the URL. What I want to achieve is fetching only plain text content inside a div. Any idea if it can be achieved.
The structure will be similar to this

```
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
     Some content inside second div
    <div class="third">
      Some more content inside third div
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I extract content I want to fetch plain text content inside an array something like this

```
Array(
 [first]=>
 [second]=>Some content inside second div
 [third]=>Some more content inside third div
);
```

I am trying to achieve this using strip_tags but somehow I am confused about splitting it up and adding it to an array. Anybody who might have any idea please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP DOMDocument get text between two SETS of tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674012/php-domdocument-get-text-between-two-sets-of-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
function clearArray($arr) {
    if(is_array($arr)) {
        foreach($arr as $element) {
            $cont=trim($element); //make sure to have cr/lf parts removed (difference between line seperator)
            if(!empty($cont)) {
                $newArray[]=$cont;
            }
        }
        return $newArray;
    }
    return false;
}
$content='<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
     Some content inside second div
    <div class="third">
      Some more content inside third div
    </div>
  </div>
</div>';
$strippedContent=strip_tags($content);
$content=explode("\n", $strippedContent);
$content=clearArray($content);
print_r($content);
```

This will output that:

```
Array ( [0] => Some content inside second div [1] => Some more content inside third div )
```

If you are retrieving this information from a foreign page I'd strongly recommend you to use DOMDocument and xpath to get the elements.

Comment: Works like a charm... Thanks. :)